# how to connect mysql databases in weka?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, weka

i want to use my mysql databases in weka in order to analysis data.
i download the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and put that in weka folder in my program Files folder, and add this path to system variable path, but when i open the weka explorer and click the openDB, i don't know what should i write in the url textbox,
i don't know completely what should i do?
the error that i saw is:

> problem connecting to database:
>   no suitable driver found for!

please give me a total guidance, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

add mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar to CLASSPATH .
or put it in weka folder, navigate to weka installation folder and run command :

%java_home%/bin/java  -Xmx300M -cp ".;weka.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar;"   weka.gui.GUIChooser

then click open DB and

- fill in the proper user+password
- put the url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*DATABASENAME*

Click Execute. The result window should show the results now.

Comment: if you are working on Linux, replace all ';' in the command with ':' and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

For Weka 3.7.10, the classpath system environment variable is not took into account (at leat under Windows 7). The only working approach for me was to modify the `RunWeka.ini` file from the Weka installation folder as follows: the `cp=` setting was modified to:

> cp=%CLASSPATH%;d:/Programs/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar

whereas only the `%CLASSPATH%;` setting was originally provided. Does not make much sense, but in worked.

Answer (score 0):

find some introduction to WEKA and the environment variable: 
http://weka.wikispaces.com/CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

Copy mysql-connector-java-X.X.XX-bin.jar to /usr/share/java/
unizip /usr/share/java/weka.jar

edit: /usr/share/java/weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props

add:
jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (with your server)

add shell
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-X.X.XX-bin.jar:
export CP=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-X.X.XX-bin.jar::/usr/share/java/:/usr/shared/java/weka.jar

execute weka:

java -cp $CP -Xmx500m weka.gui.explorer.Explorer

Ready