# Use weka with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, weka

I'm trying to use weka reading data from my local MySql database.

I put `DatabaseUtils.prop` in my home directory and launch weka as a command. I receive this message

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

But the file is being loaded, since when I try to connect, the url is already set as in my config file.

I tried to run weka from its folder using

```
java -cp ./mysql-connector-java-5.12-bin.jar -jar weka.jar
```

but this isn't working neither, since apparently using `-jar` "overrides the classpath variable" (quoted since I don't know what does that mean)

Comment: The `-cp` option is ignored when combined with `-jar`, as the jar file declares its own self-contained classpath in its manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I used this command

```
java  -Xmx300M -cp ".:weka.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar:"   weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083833/how-to-connect-mysql-databases-in-weka), to whom I replaced ';' with ':' because apparently this is how it works on Linux